# An exact and faithful functor is conservative?

Tags: category-theory

Is it true that an exact and faithful functor $F$ is conservative?

Here, exact means that it commutes with finite limits and colimits, and conservative means that if $F(f)$ is an isomorphism, then $f$ was also an isomorphism.

Comment: What does “faithful” mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally, here is the sort of thing that can go wrong. A faithful functor reflects epimorphisms and monomorphisms; it follows that if $F(f)$ is an isomorphism, then $f$ is an epimorphism and a monomorphism. But there are categories in which such a map is not an isomorphism, for example $\text{Top}$ as in MatheinBoulemenos' answer.

On the positive side, this shows that if $F$ is faithful and the domain has the property that any map which is an epimorphism and a monomorphism is an isomorphism (e.g. it's an abelian category) then $F$ is conservative with no exactness hypotheses.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no.

Consider the forgetful functor from the category of topological spaces to the category of sets. This commutes with *all* limits and colimits and is faithful, but it is not conservative.